# Rails 3.2 jquery_ujs duplicating javascript calls when assets not compressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm not sure when or how this started happening, but whenever I have in

application.js

```
//= require jquery

//= require jquery_ujs
```

And in my config file I have the following:

```
 config.assets.compress = false

 config.assets.compile = true
```

My assets will not be compressed and served individually, which I would like in my development environment.  However, as long as `//= require jquery_ujs` is present in `application.js` , all of my javascript events (such as the `:confirm` in  `<%= link_to 'Destroy All', object_destroyall_path, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>` are duplicated.  For the above link, I would get two alerts if jquery_ujs and jquery were loaded.  One alert if I get rid of jquery_ujs.  I know I'm supposed to have both jquery and jquery_ujs, so they are now both included in application.js.  This is what I get served  when my assets are not compressed:

[image]

Now, if I change the settings and compress my assets

```
 config.assets.compress = true

 config.assets.compile = false
```

I no longer have the problem of duplicate javascript events.  But I need to be able to run my assets uncompressed in development.  So what's going on?   I have tried

```
 RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:clean
 RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

But I don't think these are supposed to do anything to my uncompressed assets, correct?  I believe that jquery_ujs is being loaded twice somewhere, but I truly do not know.  In console, I am receiving no errors.  Any ideas?

Edit: just to clarify, jquery_ujs functions are the only javascript-related events that are getting duplicated.  My calls that I have scripted separately, that don't deal with ujs, are working fine.  It's only controls that utilize ujs, such as the `link_to` I have mentioned.

Comment: Any ideas anyone?  jquery_ujs is being loaded twice, that's the most logical solution.  I'm not sure where it would be loading from, or how to clear it out.